# How to change v-select option in vuetify by code without v-model

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I need to set a option in v-select by code.

I can´t use v-model.

I created a codepen in https://codepen.io/luizalves/pen/OJBYbQZ?editors=101

I need:

1. Choice a select option in v-select
2. Change the option clicking the button "Set Select"

My problem is that the button click is working only on the first time.

What am I doing wrong?

//markup

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-row align="center">
        <v-col cols="6">
          <v-subheader>
            Custom items
          </v-subheader>
        </v-col>
        <v-btn @click="setSelect()">Set Select</v-btn>
        <v-col cols="6">
          <v-select
            :value="select"
            :items="items"
            item-text="state"
            item-value="abbr"
            label="Select"
            persistent-hint
            single-line
               
          ></v-select>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

//script

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      select: 'FL' ,
      items: [
        { state: 'Florida', abbr: 'FL' },
        { state: 'Georgia', abbr: 'GA' },
        { state: 'Nebraska', abbr: 'NE' },
        { state: 'California', abbr: 'CA' },
        { state: 'New York', abbr: 'NY' },
      ],
    }
  },
  methods:{
    setSelect(){
      this.select="GA"
    },
    
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@change` event and set selected value:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      select: 'FL' ,
      items: [
        { state: 'Florida', abbr: 'FL' },
        { state: 'Georgia', abbr: 'GA' },
        { state: 'Nebraska', abbr: 'NE' },
        { state: 'California', abbr: 'CA' },
        { state: 'New York', abbr: 'NY' },
      ],
    }
  },
  methods:{
    setSelect(){
      this.select = "GA"
    },
    setSelected(e){
      this.select = e
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-row align="center">
      <v-col cols="6">
        <v-subheader>
          Custom items
        </v-subheader>
      </v-col>
      <v-btn @click="setSelect()">Set Select</v-btn>
      <v-col cols="6">
        <v-select
          :value="select"
          :items="items"
          item-text="state"
          item-value="abbr"
          label="Select"
          persistent-hint
          single-line
          @change="setSelected"
        ></v-select>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</v-app>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, Yes  I do, but,I need to set the old value when the user doesn´t want change the select option. So, in on change event I ask if the user confirm the changes. If no, How to set a different value(old value) into on change event?  If I do it, the changes is not showing in DOM